# Angular ng2-charts chartsjs-plugin-labels options not working

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm working with Angular (v9), ng2-charts, chart.js (v2.9), and chartjs-plugin-datalabels

I got my chart displaying with labels, wonderful.
Now I want to use some of the options to color the labels and position them.

I'm importing the labels like so:

```
import * as pluginDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

This is working fine:

```
public barChartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    pluginDataLabels
  }
```

This is not:

```
public barChartOptions = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      pluginDataLabels: {
        color: 'blue'
      }
    }
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. When I attempt to add any options the labels simply disappear.

[image: Here is my lovely chart with labels]

Comment: Did you try something like this: plugins: {
  pluginDataLabels: {... pluginDataLabels,
    color: 'blue'
  }
}

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html), plugins go into the `plugins` *array*. Options for the plugins go into the `options.plugins` object under the plugin id. Which appears to be `datalabels` according to the [docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#configuration).

```
public barChartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: [pluginDataLabels],
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {color: 'blue'}
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Bingo. Although the labels displayed calling it in my options array, to access label options the plugin must be called in its own plugins array.

Jeff, your help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the option `plugins.labels.fontColor` in order to obtain the desired result.

```
public barChartOptions = {
  ...
  plugins: {
    labels: {
      fontColor: 'blue'
    }
  }
```

From [`chartjs-plugin-labels`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels) documentation:

> `fontColor`: font color, can be color array for each data or function for dynamic color.

Therefore, in case you need different label colors for different data values, `fontColor` may also be defined as follows:

```
public barChartOptions = {
  ...
  plugins: {
    labels: {
      fontColor: ['blue', 'red', 'green']
    }
  }
```